# Custom Button in WooCommerce add order admin page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to add a custom button in the page where admin can manually create new order (Admin Order page).

> Admin -> Woocommerce -> order -> Add order

After i add product and when clicked edit button can i show a custom button near to `Add Meta button` ? I cannot find a hook to use.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_itemmeta', 'editable_order_meta_general' );
function editable_order_meta_general(){
  ?>
  <button class="add_values button"><?php _e( 'Add&nbsp;Custom', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
  <?php
}
```

I have added the above code. I got the result but the button is displayed soon after i add the product. I only want the button to display when i click edit button.

This is my error [image: I don't want button here]

This is my requirement. [image: I want button here]

**#UPDATE**

When i added the following code, it worked. Is it the right way ? Since woocommerce button in the same field is set `display:none;` initially .

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_itemmeta', 'editable_order_meta_general' );
function editable_order_meta_general(){
  ?>
  <div class="edit" style="display: none;">
  <button class="add_values button"><?php _e( 'Add&nbsp;Custom', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
  </div>
  <?php
}
```

**#Answer**

As mentioned by Loiz in comment, there is no hook in WooCommerce to achieve this requirement. **Have to change logic or something else**.

Comment: There is no available hook for that. You can check yourself in [**this related source code for `html-order-item-meta.php`**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-item-meta.php) … So you will have to think differently what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks  bro @LoicTheAztec. Please post your answer and i can mark it so someone will find useful

Comment: Is better if you make an update at the end of your question… Also with my first comment here it's just explicit for others.

Answer (score 1):

The hook you're looking for is `woocommerce_order_item_add_action_buttons()`

I found this tutorial: https://hungred.com/how-to/woocommerce-hook-custom-button-admin-order-page/

Hope that helps

Comment: What about it isn't working? I've added just the button display code from that tutorial and it's working for me. However, looking back, I think it's in the wrong location for what you wanted - it's adding the button down next to refund at the bottom of the order table rather than inline with each line item.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was the wrong place . This was not my requirement

Comment: I haven't been able to find the hook just for the admin order page. There probably is one - WooCommerce is very well organised in that respect, just not always brilliantly documented ;-)  However, as it is adding it where you want it, just also where you don't, you could just wrap the code in an `if ( is_admin() ) {` statement - that way it won't print the button on the customer-facing page.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time

Comment: Sorry but there is no available hooks for that in WooCommerce (in the way the author of the question want it) :(